# Send transaction failed: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number [] to BN.js instance

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, ganache

**error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "" . if you use an injected provider, please check it is properly unlocked.**

- This error occure when deploy the smart contract on metamask via
  remix IDE. I using ganache blockchain simulator and I conntect
  metamask for it. Case is one smart contract deploy correctly. Only
  this error for apply for smart contract that compiler of pragma
  solidity ^0.8.0; Actually I unable to find how this error occure.
  when search most people said reinstall the metamask but I also did it
  but error occure again and again.
- I suing wallet method
- Other thing is openzeppelin import to this script.

Please help me to solve this problem